# How to combine multiple columns in a pandas Dataframe by using apply?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read three columns from my pandas data frame and then combine with some character to form a new data frame column, the below iteration code works fine.

```
def date_creation(a,b,c):
    date=str(a) +'/'+str(b)+'/'+str(c)
    return date
df.loc["Test_FL_DATE"]=df[:,["DAY_OF_MONTH","MONTH","AYEAR"]].apply(date_creation)
```

Sample Input

[image]

Sample Output

[image]

However, if I want to do the same job by using apply or lambda. In fact, I am trying but it is not working. the code is as below which I believe is not correct. Thanks in advance for helping me out.

```
def date_creation(a,b,c):
date=str(a) +'/'+str(b)+'/'+str(c)
return date
df.loc["Test_FL_DATE"]=df[:,["DAY_OF_MONTH","MONTH","AYEAR"]].apply(date_creation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible use if need `lambda` function:

```
cols = ["DAY_OF_MONTH","MONTH","AYEAR"]
df["Test_FL_DATE"] = df[cols].astype(str).apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x))
```

Or:

```
df["Test_FL_DATE"] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.astype(str)))
```

But nicer is:

```
df["Test_FL_DATE"] = df[["DAY_OF_MONTH","MONTH","AYEAR"]].astype(str).apply('/'.join)
```

And faster solution is simply join by `+`:

```
df["Test_FL_DATE"] = (df["DAY_OF_MONTH"].astype(str) + '/' +
                      df["MONTH"].astype(str) + '/' +
                      df["AYEAR"].astype(str))
```

Comment: The lambda and apply above is not working, However the faster solution is working with a bit modification, Thanks a lot.                                                                                                                                 df["Test_FL_DATE"] = (df["DAY_OF_MONTH"].astype(str) +'/'+
                      df["MONTH"].astype(str) +'/'+
                      df["AYEAR"].astype(str))

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to use `pd.Series.str.cat`, which concatenates one string Series with other Series.

```
df['Test_FL_Date'] = (df['DAY_OF_MONTH']
    .astype(str)
    .str
    .cat([df['MONTH'], df['AYEAR'], sep='/'))
```